# Getting the list of objects from 'db' - Error - Management Studio error while generating Scripts

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, azure-sql-database

I tried to generate Scripts from our companies Azure SQL-Database. As I did two weeks before I connected to the DB with my Management Studio Client and ran the "Generate Scripts"-Wizard in the Context of the concerned DB. The wizard failed at ***"Getting the list of objects from 'db'."*** and pointed out the following Stack Trace:

Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.SqlScriptPublishException: An error occurred while scripting the objects. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Die angegebene Umwandlung ist ungültig. at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.IPropertyDataDispatch.SetPropertyValue(Int32 index, Object value) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PropertyDispatcher.SetValue(Int32 index, Object value) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PropertyCollection.SetValue(Int32 index, Object value) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.AddObjectPropsFromDataReader(IDataReader reader, Boolean skipIfDirty, Int32 startColIdx, Int32 endColIdx) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ImplInitialize(String[] fields, OrderBy[] orderby) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.OnPropertyMissing(String propname, Boolean useDefaultValue) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PropertyCollection.RetrieveProperty(Int32 index, Boolean useDefaultOnMissingValue) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PropertyCollection.GetPropertyObject(Int32 index) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetPropertyOptional(String propName) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column.EmbedDefaultConstraints() at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column.GetPropagateInfo(PropagateAction action) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetPropagateInfoForDiscovery(PropagateAction action) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyDiscoverer.GetScriptableChildren(List`1 propInfoList, PropagateAction propagateAction) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyDiscoverer.SfcChildrenDiscovery(HashSet`1 discoveredUrns) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyDiscoverer.Discover(IEnumerable`1 urns) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.Discover(IEnumerable`1 urns) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.DiscoverOrderScript(IEnumerable`1 urns) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptWorker(List`1 urns, ISmoScriptWriter writer) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.Script(Urn[] urns, ISmoScriptWriter writer) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.SqlScriptGenerator.DoScript(ScriptOutputOptions outputOptions) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.GeneratePublishPage.worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)

The @@VERSION-Query returns the following record:

Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 11.0.9231.13
    Jul 15 2015 11:58:32
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation

And here is some additional information copied from the SSMS-Help:

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                        12.0.4100.1
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        12.0.4100.1
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                        6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML                        3.0 6.0
Microsoft Internet Explorer                        9.11.9600.17843
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                        6.1.7601

Can you tell me what's going wrong here?

Thanks in Advance.

Alan

Comment: I do not get any diagnostic information at all when the generation of the script fails. How did you obtain diagnostics?

Comment: Honestly... Since its more than a year ago from now, I don't remember anymore. But it wasn't hard to find. Maybe in the output/report? :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem . To resolve I switched to another directory that sql server could write .

Worked for me.

I hope you solve your problem , since the error message is not clear.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! I finally "solved" the problem by simply buying a new PC (since it was anyway high time for me to do so, lol ;-). However, I still didn't find out what the source of this strange error actually was. Since I'm working on my new PC I never had this issue anymore. I will keep your approach in mind for the case that I will run into this kind of trouble again.

Answer (score 2):

Check server free space.
I resolved same problem by make free space on server.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you can write to the file in that folder. In my case, I was saving the script in the C:\ drive, for example, c:\script.sql, and after I changed to another folder it worked.

Comment: Similar problem.  Tried to change the folder - no go - tried to restart - still no go.  Selected was data_only option.  Switching to data and schema allowed the server to write the files.  (SQL Server 2014 (SP3) (KB4022619) 12.0.6024.0 (x64) Sp 7 2018)